# returning a lambda without std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, return-type, higher-order-functions

Consider the following function which is returning a lambda:

```
std::function<int()> make_counter()
{
    int i = 0;
    return [=]() mutable { return i++; };
}
```

Is it possible to return the actual lambda type, without wrapping it into a `std::function`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

C++11: No. Every lambda expression has, I quote (§5.1.2/3):

> [...] a **unique**, unnamed non-union class type [...]

This effectively means that you can't know the lambda's type without knowing the corresponding expression first.

Now, if you didn't capture anything, you could use the conversion to function pointer and return that (a function pointer type), but that's pretty limiting.

As @Luc noted in the Lounge, if you're willing to replace your `make_counter` (and if it isn't a template, or overloaded, or something), the following would work:

```
auto const make_counter = [](int i = 0) {
  return [i]() mutable { return i++; };
};
```

---

C++1y: Yes, through return-type deduction for normal functions ([N3582](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3582.html)).

Comment: That lambda expression is not valid C++11, either. The return type deduction would not work if the body contains more than just the `return expression;` (§5.1.2,4)

Comment: Technically you could return `my_not_STD_function` that just reimplements something basically equivalent...

Comment: Note that one of the reason for this is that the type of a lambda accounts for more than just its signature. Each captured variable (whether by copy or reference) need be taken into account as well and those are only known by examining the lambda body.

Answer (score 10):

If you cheat and use return type deduction, [yes you can (Link)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=87c1b7f4deaf36b1749bac254cf466bd-a2574bcf90a5184e7a985df72132c580).

Note this is only possible beyond C++11 itself, though it can be accomplished in regular, non-warning-inducing C++11 using lambdas (that is, a lambda inside of a lambda that returns that lamba).

Comment: Not C++11, not (yet) standard.

Comment: Yeah, C++ still being slow. =[

Comment: @Fred see the link again, and pay attention to the command-line used to compile.

Comment: What the correspondent C++ expression of type "Z12make_countervEUlvE_"? Can I define that lambda in the way old c++98 do without both std::function and auto? If the answer is yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with some lambda tricks inspired by [this blog post](http://pfultz2.com/blog/2014/09/02/static-lambda/).

The first step is to provide a helper to make a lambda a literal type:

```
template<class F>
struct literal_lambda_t {
    static_assert(std::is_empty<F>(), "Lambdas must be empty (have no captures)");

    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) const -> decltype(
        std::declval<F const&>()(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    ) {
        // since the object is empty, reinterpreting it should be safe
        return reinterpret_cast<const F&>(*this)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template<class F>
constexpr literal_lambda_t<typename std::remove_reference<F>::type> literal_lambda(F &&f) {
    return {};
}
```

Now you can declare a "private" function that takes advantage of the fact that lambdas *do* have return-type deduction:

```
namespace detail {
    static constexpr auto make_counter = literal_lambda([](){
        int i = 0;
        return [=]() mutable { return i++; };
    });
}
```

Finally, you can declare your real function in terms of this private lambda:

```
auto make_counter() -> decltype(detail::make_counter()) {
    return detail::make_counter();
}
```

---

This approach even works for templated functions:

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename T>
    struct typed_counter_helper {
        // can't template this, so have to template an enclosing struct
        static constexpr auto f = literal_lambda([](){
            T i = 0;
            return [=]() mutable { return i++; };
        });
    };
}
template<typename T>
auto make_typed_counter() -> decltype(typed_counter_helper<T>::f()) {
    return typed_counter_helper<T>::f::make_counter();
}
```